# Generate random number with no side effect

Tags: scala, side-effects, purely-functional

Recentely I began to study functional programming paradigm using Scala as reference language.
I come up with this problem: How to generate a random number with no side effect ?
Googling I found this solution:

```
package fp.crazy-bankers.utils

    object Rng {
        def next(seed : Int) : (Int,Int) = {
            val newSeed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0x FFFFFFFFFFFFL
            val number = (newSeed >>> 16).toInt
            (newSeed, number)
        }
    }
```

Basically here the state (the seed) is managed passing it explicitly on every invocation of next method.
This implementation works for me until I call it from the same place because in this way is easy to keep care of the state and pass it on each invocation.

But what if I need a random number in different places?
For example if I call next method from 10 different actors,
in this case each actor is able to pass its local copy of the state only.

Basically in this way there is no global knowledge of the state across all actors,so
risks is different actors get the same random number.
How to solve this issue?

Have I to find someway to manage globally the state or try with a completely different pattern?

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know why it is important to you that calling the random number generator has no side effect. Because introducing any kind of global state will take that away again. Which may or may not be a problem, depending on your requirements.

Comment: "risks is different actors get the same random number". If they start with completely independent seeds, that risk seems fairly minimal. Also, is it really a problem if that happens? You are using a simple, non-cryptographic PRNG to begin with, a stronger one combined with strong seed generation may help if it is.

Comment: My goal is to use a purely functional design style.

Comment: Then you need to wrap the random number generator into an "effect type". Because calling it will have a side-effect, otherwise there is no way the function can return a different number when called the next time. This is similar to reading user input or checking the system time. You are leaving "pure function" and need to work with "effects" (which are pure functions that describe actions that *when run* will have some side-effects). Look at ZIO or Monix.

Comment: Actors _(specially **Akka**)_ and pure functional programming are like water and oil. You can mix actors with some degree of functional programming techniques, but the moment you decided to add the _"pure"_ you are doomed, since each paradigm is very opinionated about how to manage state, and both ways are somewhat opposite from each other.

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce a separate actor that will reply with next random number.

For example actors will send `GetNextRandomNumber` to this actor and it will reply `NextRandomNumber(number)`.

This actor will manage its state (`seed`) itself.

Actually sending a message to this actor will be a side effect.

Normally generating a random number is a side effect because function that is free of side effects can't produce different outputs on the same input.

The idea of functional programming is not to avoid side effects but to control them. For example with `IO`, `State` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can share mutable state between different places using the `Ref` construct. There are several implementations of it in Scala:

ZIO Ref: https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_ref

cats-effect Ref: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/concurrency/ref

However this requires you to pass the Ref explicitly to every place that is going to use it. This is a feature, not a bug, because it makes it easier to identify all the places where some piece of mutable state is used – there is no way to have global mutable state.

But since you mentioned actors, I doubt that you're really doing pure FP anyway. There's basically no way to do that at least with Akka, because even sending a message between actors is a side effect.

Comment: I agree with you, actors wasn't a correct example.Anyway I looked into Ref concept. Basically I sitll have a side effect inside Ref but with this wrapper it is possible to hide it to all Ref users.If I understood correctly there is no way to solve the problem I indicated in a purely fp way. Only possible approach is to confine and control the side effect (I.e:use Monad).

Comment: You can solve the problem in a purely functional way, but every function that needs to generate a random number has to be given a seed by the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

You use a different type of PRNG, that supports splitting.  Then you split the generator on the main actor as many times as you need, and send one subgenerator to each of the other actors.

As an example, [JAX does this](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#RNGs-and-State) by using a generator called [threefry](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/master/design_notes/prng.md).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "use a purely functional design style" then you have to pass a seed to every function that requires "random" numbers. There is no other choice. All other options require a side-effect or lose referential transparency.

So if you use random numbers in multiple functions, you have to provide a different seed to each of those functions.

The seed is just a compact way of representing an infinite sequence of random numbers, so an alternative is to generate the random numbers outside the function and past the values to the function rather than the seed.